# MongoDB Sort on high volume data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Using NodeJS, if I rename my `telemName` table and grab fresh data, this code works absolutely fine. Always has. However, the collection I have now has breached Total Results: 1649272

```
db.collection(telemName).find(options).sort({ "d" : 1 }).toArray(function (err, telemetryData) {
    console.log(telemetryData.length, "data points to insert");
    var newlastInsert = telemetryData[telemetryData.length - 1].d;
    callback(null, db, telemetryData, newlastInsert)
});
```

Why does my sort fail, ergo yielding this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Obviously it means no data is being returned, and I can guarantee you, 100%, that the field I'm sorting on is `{ "d" : 1 }` and has worked until now with no changes.

Do large data sets over a million or so simply break Mongo sorting? If I run the application fresh, it works fine. The table grows, the program runs.

For reference, here is a sample dataset straight from my database:

[image]

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Have you read this snippit from the docs? https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions...do you see any errors in the database logs?

Comment: What does `err` contain in the `toArray` callback? Anyway, for good sort performance, it needs to be able to use an index.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was indexed already. However, there's a chance I may have removed it because I messed with the collection come to think of it.. Let me see the error log

Comment: `MongoError: Executor error during find command: OperationFailed Sort operation used more than the maximum 33554432 bytes of RAM. Add an index, or specify a smaller limit.` Yup...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/#restrictions):

> When unable to obtain the sort order from an index, MongoDB will sort
>   the results in memory, which requires that the result set being sorted
>   is less than 32 megabytes.

Go ahead and create an index for your sort (example):

```
db.records.createIndex( { a: 1 } )
```

Or add a [limit()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit)